# Under what circumstances IPv4 conntrack drops packets?

Tags: linux, iptables, ipv4

I always thought that IPv4 Connection Tracking ( a.k.a. `conntrack` ) is a passive module, that just reads packets and tracks them, so later **other modules** can use that collected information to decide about the fate of related packets (e.g. packets belonging to the same L4 connection).

However, recently I stumbled upon this comment in the `conntrack`'s [source code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.14.151/source/net/ipv4/netfilter/nf_conntrack_l3proto_ipv4.c#L183):

> "Connection tracking may drop packets, but never alters them, so make it the first hook."

..which indicates that `conntrack` is not just a passive observer, but it actually can DROP packets !!!

Under what circumstances does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the order of operations. Conntrack would need to be relatively early anyway. If it doesn't modify packets so much the better; assuming pristine packets must simplify something.

If connection tracking fails, what else can be done with untracked packets but drop them? A firewall policy to automatically allow responses to your flows no longer works.

[netfilter FAQ mentions a few reasons for failure](https://netfilter.org/documentation/FAQ/netfilter-faq-3.html), as this can happen to NATs too. I imagine it gets annoying for niche workloads where [conntrack no longer scales](https://www.projectcalico.org/when-linux-conntrack-is-no-longer-your-friend/).